# nested union select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, derby, javadb

Is it possible to group  result of my sql SELECT statements without creating temp table to sum and group in one statement? I have a table saving the total of debit and credit amount for credit account No. and debit account No.
and put zero for opposite field, I made first grouppage with below union select statement and I need to sum the output based on repeated accounts name 
I can get this the same easily or have to load it temp table? my select statement as below

```
select  journal_drname  AS ACCNAME, sum(amount) AS DEBT,0 as CREDIT
FROM JOURNAL GROUP BY journal_drname 
 UNION select  journal_crname  AS ACCNAME, 0 as DEBT,sum(amount) AS   
 CREDIT,
 FROM JOURNAL GROUP BY journal_crname
```

returning data like:

```
ACCNAME      DEBIT     CREDIT
--------   -------     ------
CASH        0           1,000
CASH        900          0
CASH        300          0
BANK        200          0
BANK        400          0
```

can I summery above to be grouped as follows:

```
ACCNAME      DEBIT     CREDIT
--------   -------     ------
CASH        200          0
BANK        600          0
```

And I want to join the results of these to be cut as above.

I'm trying to avoid using a temp table, but if that's the only practical way to do this, I'd like to know more about using temp tables in this fashion.

I also tried to do some kind join and union but not satisfy a conditional and I couldn't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Your results do not make sense unless `journal_drname` has unusual characters in it.

Comment: Rephrased: How is it that both cash and bank have a 0 credit and values for debit for each accname?  The SQL you propose negate that possibility.

Comment: yes i have two case for the account name sometime coming credit in this case i have to load the account name in journal_crname and if the same account name came debit i have to load it in journal_crname field so i have two column loading on foreign account name journal_drname and journal_crname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say your query is working, lets call your union query as a table

```
( ...... ) myTable
```

then just create a subquery to get the final step

```
SELECT ACCNAME,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CREDIT - DEBT) < 0 THEN - SUM(CREDIT - DEBT)
            ELSE 0
       END DEBT,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CREDIT - DEBT) > 0 THEN   SUM(CREDIT - DEBT)
            ELSE 0
       END CREDIT
FROM ( ...... ) myTable
GROUP BY ACCNAME
```

Comment: The statement looks perfect but still gave me error message not accepting last line "GROUP BY ACCNAME" i wll keep checking and revert thxs

Comment: YES NOW WORKING GREATS THXS ALOT SIR

Comment: yes i missed to put the inner table aliases  myTable that's why.Thxs

Answer (score 2):

If you want only one row per subquery, then remove the `group by`:

```
select  'CASH' as ACCNAME, sum(amount) AS DEBT, 0 as CREDIT
FROM JOURNAL 
UNION ALL
select  'BANK' as ACCNAME, 0 as DEBT, sum(amount) AS  CREDIT
FROM JOURNAL;
```

(Note:  the `ACCNAME` values might be reversed.)

Important:  You should be using `UNION ALL` for this type of query rather than `UNION`.  There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates, unless you intend to remove duplicates.

Also, your original query should have worked, unless there are unusual characters in the accname fields.

Comment: I like it... but I'm confused by ", unless you intend to remove duplicates"  By definition, there can't be duplicates.  based on the SQL.  CASH and BANK negate duplicates from the union, and internally since each one has only one row, there can't be duplicates.  Perhaps you need where clause for journal_drname  in each part of union, one for bank one for cash.

Comment: @xQbert . . . `UNION` always incurs the overhead of removing duplicates even if there are none (I say "always"; but I suppose some database somewhere might identify some special cases that short-circuit the duplicate elimination).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select ACCNAME, 
    CASE WHEN sum(DEBT)>sum(CREDIT) THEN sum(DEBT)-sum(CREDIT) ELSE 0 AS DEBT, 
    CASE WHEN sum(DEBT)<sum(CREDIT) THEN sum(CREDIT)-sum(DEBT) ELSE 0 AS CREDIT 
FROM (
    select  journal_drname  AS ACCNAME, 
        sum(amount) AS DEBT,
        0 as CREDIT
    FROM JOURNAL GROUP BY journal_drname 
UNION 
    select journal_crname  AS ACCNAME, 
        0 as DEBT,
        sum(amount) AS CREDIT,
 FROM JOURNAL GROUP BY journal_crname
) group by ACCNAME
```

Comment: I belive in mySql subqueries *must* have an aliast to work.